# Are there any plugins for broadcasting events in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to broadcast a message across microservices, whenever any database is updated.

Example:
Stock value keeps changing, how do i notify all to use the latest value everytime the stock value is updated.

Can anyone suggest any tools or plugins for the same which could be embedded with spring boot.
An example code would be very helpful

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-pub-sub

Comment: I think is is what Spring Boot 2.0 and reactive Spring is all about.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as to what problem you're trying to solve.
Are you trying to prevent caching of the old value from the web clients?

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more complex, then you can find tons of examples with AMQP, Spring JMS, Redis pub-sub in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484212258) book.

One easy solution for basic state changes, would be instead [spring-cloud-bus](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/).

> Spring Cloud Bus links nodes of a distributed system with a
>   lightweight message broker. This can then be used to broadcast state
>   changes (e.g. configuration changes) or other management instructions.
>   The only implementation currently is with an AMQP broker as the
>   transport, but the same basic feature set (and some more depending on
>   the transport) is on the roadmap for other transports.

A common use case is the change in the config server that needs to be updated in all the microservices. While normally we would change the value in the config server and then hit the refresh endpoint for each service, the config cloud bus updates them all making the process easier.